# Find elegant way to wrap runnable method and pass it as a function in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, runnable

Im with java 11, Let's say I have multiple runnable methods all them are same structure except the number of parameters as in example:

```
private Runnable deleteIndex(String targetIndex) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                iIndexerManagementService.deleteIndex(targetIndex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Cannot perform delete:", e);
            }
        };
    }
    
    
private Runnable deleteDataBySource(String targetIndex, String source) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                indexerDocumentService.deleteBySource(targetIndex, source);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Cannot perform delete:", e);
            }
        };
    }
    
    
private Runnable createDeleteTaskByScanID(String targetIndex, String scandId, String source) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                indexerDocumentService.deleteByScanId(targetIndex, scandId, source);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Cannot perform delete:", e);
            }
        };
} .... 
  and more ....
```

Later on I use it like here on each runnable method:

```
    public void submitDeleteIndexTask(String targetIndex) {
       Optional.ofNullable(syncControlRepository.findByName(CATALOG_ENTITY_TYPE_KEYWORD))
                        .ifPresent(strategy -> {
                            Future<?> future =  uploadersExecutor.submit(deleteIndex(targetIndex));
                            if (featureFlagEnabled && config.isTestProfile()) {
                                try {
                                    future.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    log.error("Cannot wait on thread block:", e);
                                }
                            }
                    });
            } 
.... and more
```

I works perfect.

But I want to find nicer elegant way not to hold lots of runnable methods in class cause  it might be more.
My purpose create 1 generic runnable wrapper to be able pass any kind of function so when I'll use it i will pass only the function itself and the parameters to invoke.

I thought about this way, bit i'm not sure it is correct

```
// generic runnable wrapper to pass any function

    public Runnable runAsync(Function foo, Object o) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                foo.apply(o);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Cannot perform delete:", e);
            }
        };
    }
```

and then it should be 1 general method to be able receive function to fit the runnables methods:

```
public void runGeneralAsync(... HERE PASS FUNCTION ..??. ) {
        Optional.ofNullable(syncControlRepository.findByName(CATALOG_ENTITY_TYPE_KEYWORD))
                .ifPresent(strategy -> {
                    Future<?> future =  uploadersExecutor.submit(runAsync(....FUNCTOIN... ?? ));
                    if (featureFlagEnabled && config.isTestProfile()) {
                        try {
                            future.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            log.error("Cannot wait on thread block:", e);
                        }
                    }
            });
    }
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is tantamount to 'stringly typed' / dynamic, and is fundamentally unjavalike. You may think you want this; you don't. The entire java ecosystem will be fighting you every step of the way if you try.

NB: Your `runGeneralAsync` is deplorably bad - you're really abusing Optional here. That code is a long-winded way of saying: Look up a thingie, if it does exist, do this, if it does not, silently do nothing. Aside from the long-windedness (there's nothing wrong with `if`!), "Do nothing" is a horrible fallback. Horrible in the sense of: A single bug in the name or setup means nothing happens, so, you'll be chasing that bug for hours. An NPE takes 1 minute. If you ever write code where you can't fathom `null` occuring, just write it. If null does happen you **want** that exception, so you know where to fix things.

At any rate:

Instead, Runnable, itself, is the answer. Wrap lambdas in lambdas.

You're thinking of something like:

```java
// API:
public void runGeneralAsync(String methodName, Object... args) {
  // Lots of reflective shenanigans to find it.
  // Lots of issues with dealing with exceptions -
  // what if the method name does not exist? What if the wrong amount
  // of args were passed? Or the wrong type? Or there is an overload?

  // .. and then of course code to stick it all into an executor.submit
}

// usage:

runGeneralAsync("deleteIndexTask", "my-index");
```

but what you want to do is something like this:

```java
public void runGeneralAsync(Runnable task) {
  uploadersExecutor.submit(runAsync(....));
}

// usage:

runGeneralAsync(() -> deleteIndex("my-index"));
```

Depending on needs, you may want to use `Callable` instead of `Runnable` here (you can return things, and throw things).

Comment: "Stringly" typed – you mean "strongly" typed? Otherwise I am lost …

Comment: No, that wasn't a typo. "Stringly" typed is the opposite of strongly typed: That you stick method names in a string literal, thus losing type safety, IDE support, and so much more - not worth it. Note how in the 'you're thinking of something like...' section I have `"deleteIndexTask"` - that's the method you want, it's in a string - that's a "stringly typed" API. stringly typed is bad, you don't want that.